# Get Item From List<T> and update a property on that Item

Tags: c#

I have a List of type Person that I would like to update DisplayValue based on DisplayName.  How can I accomplish this?

```
public class Person
{
     public string DisplayName { get; set; }
     public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
     ... other properties
}
```

Comment: >>update DisplayValue based on DisplayName<< Could you please clarify, based how? and update how?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I think this is what you're after.

```
List<Person> persons;
var person = persons.Find(p => p.DisplayName == "Fred");
person.DisplayValue = "Flinstone";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = ... List<Person> from somewhere.
foreach(var person in list){
   person.DisplayValue = person.DisplayName;
}
```

Comment: it would be much better if he update `public string DisplayValue { get; set; }` to `public string DisplayValue { get { return this.DisplayName; } }`

Comment: He actually probably intended to do what Jason suggested. My answer really doesn't make too much sense, but it does do what the question asked? I think?

Answer (score 0):

create a private variable, explicitly define the getter and setter, and modify Display value accordingly in the setter.

```
public class Person
{
    private string displayName;
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return displayName; }
        set
        {
            displayName = value;
            DisplayValue = value + " is a value";
        }
    }
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
    //... other properties
}
```